AJAX request doesn't work (500 internal server error)
So I've been working to import a certain variable into an external PDF using DOMPDF.
For this,2 files (.php extensions) are used:
1)First file contains the function that creates that variable (in Javascript).
2)The second,file 2, is the structure and form of the PDF output file
The problem is that I wanted to move the variable created by the javascript function (in File 1) into file 2,I originally tried setting a global variable ,didn't work......not sure but for some reason,Javascript doesn't work with the second file,and yes,('isJavascriptEnabled') is set to True.
So I decided to use PHP instead,using AJAX to transfer the variable into server-side,unfortunatly I couldn't transfer the variable into the server-side,and I don't understand why.
So I decided to use an external text file,and this too,didn't work,which is the problem I'm posting today.
I have tried AJAX with the same first file to put it inside an external .txt file:
`    <?php
if(isset($_POST['commandeCodeValue'])) {
    $commandeCodeValue = $_POST['commandeCodeValue'];
    $file = "BDC.txt";
    file_put_contents($file, $commandeCodeValue);
    echo "Data saved successfully";
    exit; // Stop further execution
}
else{
    file_put_contents("BDC.txt","No data found");
}
?>`

`<!-- JavaScript -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#code').on('input', function() {
            var code = $(this).val();
            $('#commandeCode').text(code);
            window.commandeCodeValue = code;
            alert(code);

            // Send the value to the server using AJAX
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "", // Send it to the same page, adjust if needed
                data: { commandeCodeValue: code }, // Send the value as data
                success: function(response) {
                    // Handle the response from the server if needed
                    alert('Data sent successfully');
                    // You can perform further actions here after the AJAX call is successful
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    // Handle the error if AJAX request fails
                    alert('Error sending data: ' + error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
`

That didn't work,given that the PHP part executes first,so I heard the best way to do is to create a third .PHP file(I called it counter.php),so I did
File 1:
`
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#code').on('input', function() {
            var code = $(this).val();
            $('#commandeCode').text(code);
            window.commandeCodeValue = code;
            alert(code);

            // Send the value to the server using AJAX
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "counter.php", // Send it to the same page, adjust if needed
                data: { commandeCodeValue: code }, // Send the value as data
                success: function(response) {
                    // Handle the response from the server if needed
                    alert('Data sent successfully');
                    // You can perform further actions here after the AJAX call is successful
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    // Handle the error if AJAX request fails
                    alert('Error sending data: ' + error);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
`

`File 3:(counter.php)
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['commandeCodeValue'])) {
    $commandeCodeValue = $_POST['commandeCodeValue'];
    $file = "BDC.txt";
    file_put_contents($file, $commandeCodeValue);
    echo "Data saved successfully";
} else {
    $file = "BDC.txt";
    file_put_contents($file, "25&");
    echo "No data received";
}
    ?>`
`


For some reason I'm getting an odd error,I recieve "500 (Internal Server Error)"
when I opened the error in a new tab,I got this:

`
Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\system\database\DB_query_builder.php on line 1429
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean

Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Line Number: 1429

Backtrace:`


I thought also of using AJAX to send the variable to the File 2,I got the same error
I really am our of ideas at this point,all I wanted to do was to make the Javascript variable (called code) from file 1 into my second file(File 2).
Global variable didn't work.
AJAX didn't work.
External (txt) file didn't work.
Any help will be appreciated.

The PHP error message is explaining exactly what is going on. A 500 error is a server error.

The code you've posted has nothing to do with the error message. The error is happening in DB_query_builder.php, I'm guessing because it's not making a database connection. But none of the PHP code you posted has anything to do with the database.

Understood,thanks for the clarification.
I'm still learning,so deep apologies.

No problem. As per [ask] please always ensure you provide a [mre] of the issue for us. The error message clearly states the filename and line number
